# how to check in selenium that the click happens?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

this is my original screenshot. 
[image]

And this is the screenshot after I have click the on-off area on it. 
[image]

This is the original html for the on-off area:

```
<div region="child-0" class="togglebar-item inline-block region region-child-0">
    <div data-view-name="anonymous-view-11401" data-render-count="2">
        <div class="ftnt-on-off-switch-ct">        
            <div class="ftnt-on-off-switch inline-block">        
                <input type="checkbox" id="ftnt-on-off-input--toggle-0" class="" action="action" data-mkey="1325" data-id="toggle-0">        
                <label for="ftnt-on-off-input--toggle-0"></label>        
                <div class="slider"></div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the html after the on-off area has been clicked.

```
<div region="child-0" class="togglebar-item inline-block region region-child-0">
    <div data-view-name="anonymous-view-11492" data-render-count="2">
        <div class="ftnt-on-off-switch-ct">        
            <div class="ftnt-on-off-switch inline-block">        
                <input type="checkbox" id="ftnt-on-off-input--toggle-0" class="" action="action" checked="" data-mkey="1325" data-id="toggle-0">        
                <label for="ftnt-on-off-input--toggle-0"></label>        
                <div class="slider"></div>    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My question is: 
**In selenium python, after I click the on/off area, how may I detect the on/off happens ???**

I need to add a test case for this, as sometimes even People have click the on-off, it never happens.

Comment: Is there any change in the HTML?

Comment: the only thing that i have noticed is this  >>> checked="" in the afterwards html, inside the <input ...>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternately you may use something like this as well  . I have tried this approach in java and you can definitely use it in python as well.

`String color = element.getCssValue("color");`

You can get the color from the style tab in the inspector and check if the color has changed

Answer (score 0):

```
# if its checked checkboxes
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.cssSelector, "input:checked[type='checkbox']")))
# if its not checked checkboxes
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.cssSelector, "input:not(:checked)[type='checkbox']")))
```